# How exactly TLS/SSL works regarding client certificate?

Tags: security, ssl

I read the TLS 1.2 RFC, but i couldn't find (or understand) how client certificate authentication works.

What i understood is that the server may request the client certificate and the client should provide it, but what exactly does it provide? How does the client prove he owns the private key (I assume he gets some challenge and encrypts it, but what exactly does he encrypt)?

I will be happy if someone could shed some light on this part of the protocol.

EDIT : 
What i'm trying to achieve is man in the middle (like fiddler does for server certificate).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can copy/paste from OpenSSL wiki:
https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL_and_TLS_Protocols#Client_Authentication

Basically Client sends the Client Certificate to server that match the CA DN given by Server. Client then sends a Cerificate Verify that uses its private key to prove he owns it.

A Client Certificate authentication requires the client to own a Certificate and have the corresponding private key. Client never sends its private key, but use it to prove he has the corresponding pair key of public key advertised within Certificate.

What he digests? a digest of the whole handshakes exchanges so far.
If server manage to verify this with public key and it matches digest of whole handshake so far (computed at server side) then i prove two things :

- client owns private key ( else deciphering with public key would not be correct )
- client is at the other side of this handshake, it protects against replay of a client Certificate Verify from another handshake.

So yes challenge is in fact whole handshake messages.

Comment: So i can't do "man in the middle" when client certificate is activated ? (with server certificate i can, because i'm installing on the client my CA) ?

Comment: you would need to make your server trust you just like you did for the client and then create client certificate with what server trust and plays your side. Else i don't see how you could pass the client Certificate identity as it is without breaking its private key. You can still try to pass the CertificateVerify as it is and look if the server actualy performs the verification ( some wrong implementations could miss it ).

Comment: and i you manage to do man in the middle with a client certificate, i would be very interested to know how you did it.