# What does --key mean in cUrl

Tags: curl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I started to "play" with curl and SSL. I'm working with client certificate and I'm using curl to send API request to a server. In the curl command I specify the client certificate, the private key file and the passphrase. Why I need to specify the private key using `--key` option? Am I sending the file to the server or is just a way to inform curl how to decrypt the received data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not sending your private key to the server. The `key` is used so that server can verify that client certificate you are providing, was indeed issued to you and you possess the corresponding private key. It's used to sign a piece of data that was sent by server. Only this signed data is transmitted not the key. Server then uses your certificate (which was signed by CA trusted by server) to decrypt data and confirm you are in a possession of the corresponding private key. (for more on how TLS checks client certificate during TLS handshake see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34533228/7109330) or [this shorter one one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26871940/7109330))

This is similar to how you need to provide, usually PKCS#12 file, to your browser, in order to access web pages that require client certificate authentication. The PCKS#12 is an archive format that contains bundled certificate and private key. `curl` allows you to use this format in `--cert` option as well, from `man page`:

> -E, --cert <certificate[:password]>
> (TLS)  Tells  curl  to use the specified client certificate file when getting a file with HTTPS, FTPS or another SSL-based protocol. The certificate must be in PKCS#12 format if using Secure Transport, or PEM format if
> using any other engine.

Comment: So if I understood correctly... in the certificate (in the client side) there is the server public key and some information signed with the client private key. The server will receive the certificate, decrypt the message with server private key and from the decrypted message check the signature.. right?

Comment: For client authentication, the server will decrypt message with public key from the certificate, that was sent by the client along with the encrypted message. And the certificate must be signed by the CA that is trusted by the server, so that server knows it can trust that client. In parallel to that, client sends data signed by the server's public key, which is decrypted by server's private key. This data is part of the establishing TLS connection and this is same in every TLS handshake.

Comment: And why I need to specify the passphrase? Who will use it and when? Thanks

Comment: This is the passphrase to decrypt your client private key. By default openssl asks for passphrase during new public/private key generation. You can leave it blank, then you wouldn't need to provide passphrase, but private key would be stored unencrypted on your disk. The `curl` will use the passphrase to decrypt the client private key prior to using it to encrypt data, which will be sent to server.

Comment: You might be familiar with passphrase used for SSH key. During SSH keypair generation you are asked for passphrase. Later, when you are connecting to remote server you will be prompted for passphrase to decrypt SSH private key and connection will be established. In SSH use case you can use `ssh-agent` to store decrypted SSH private key in memory while your login session is running. This way you don't have to enter passphrase every time you are using SSH to connect to remote host.